# How to resolve the error TypeError: x is not a function for testing of the following function in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

**Function that I want to test**

```
function setWebsite(website){

    curWebsite = website;
    var r = /:\/\/(.[^/]+)/;
    myWebsite = website.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/,'');
    return myWebsite;

  }
```

**code in test folder**

```
const { setWebsite } = require('./popup');
test('should give current website name', () => {
    const text = setWebsite('https://www.youtube.com/');
    expect(text).toBe('youtube');

});
```

**Error message**

```
TypeError: setWebsite is not a function
```

Comment: try to use `module.export`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a function in another file you need to export it:

```
function setWebsite(website) {

  curWebsite = website;
  var r = /:\/\/(.[^/]+)/;
  myWebsite = website.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/, '');
  return myWebsite;

}

module.exports.setWebsite = setWebsite;
```

And you are requiring a module not a function:

```
const popupModule = require('./popup');
test('should give current website name', () => {
    const text = popupModule.setWebsite('https://www.youtube.com/');
    expect(text).toBe('youtube');

});
```

Comment: its now giving an error `popupModule.setWebsite is not a function`

Comment: you probably not requiring the module correctly, you need to require the module relative to the test file and give it the relative path to the popup file

Comment: I didn't quite get you, this is my first attempt at testing functions

Comment: ..thats why i am facing a little more problem